# How can I modify post titles before Timber::render?

Tags: wordpress, timber

I'm trying to avoid widows/orphans in my post titles that appear throughout my site by modifying the `{{ post.title }}` output in single.php before it is rendered in my single.twig template.

I'd like to use something like this PHP to insert a nonbreaking space:

```
$title = preg_replace( '|([^\s])\s+([^\s]+)\s*$|', '$1&nbsp;$2', $title);
```

What's the proper way to get a post title (or all posts titles), and send them back to the Timber context before I use `Timber::render()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `title()` method for a Timber Post object is mostly just a pass-through for Wordpress' own `the_title()` function.

Here is the relevant code for the `title()` method:

```php
public function title() {
    if ( $rd = $this->get_revised_data_from_method('title') ) {
        return $rd;
    }
    return apply_filters('the_title', $this->post_title, $this->ID);
}
```

Ignoring the if statement (it's there to help with updating the preview for a post), the method simply gets the post's title from the database and applies the Wordpress [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter to it.

That means you can modify your title output by modifying the `the_title` filter. This previous StackOverflow answer provides a good summary of how to use it:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/how-to-change-the-blog-title-with-add-filter-details-below

I have not tested the code below, but I think something like this should work given your requirements:

```php
add_filter('the_title', 'modify_all_titles', 10, 2);

function modify_all_titles($title, $id) {
  return preg_replace( '|([^\s])\s+([^\s]+)\s*$|', '$1&nbsp;$2', $title);
}
```

It's important to note that this will change ALL titles for ALL posts in every place that `the_title()` or `{{ post.title }}` is used on the site. If you want to limit the change to certain situations, you have two options:

1. Use conditionals inside your filter function to modify the title (or not) differently in different circumstances. For example, you could apply your modifications only on a specific custom post type while returning the default title in all other instances.
2. Define a new context value for your modified title value and use that instead of `post.title` in your twig template.

For example, in your PHP template file you could add the following after `$context` and `$post` have been defined but before `Timber::render()`:

```php
$context['custom_title'] = preg_replace( '|([^\s])\s+([^\s]+)\s*$|', '$1&nbsp;$2', $title);
```

Then in your Twig file, you can use `{{ custom_title }}` instead of `{{ post.title }}`.

Finally, if you're into object oriented PHP, you could [extend the `Timber/Post` class](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/) to define your own `title()` method. The details for that approach are outside the scope of this question, but may be worth looking into if you want to harness the full power of Timber.